# matrix equation $(A-B)CA=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A,B,C$ be $n\times n$ matrices with real entries such that $A$ is invertible. if $(A-B)CA=B$ show that $AC(A-B)=B$.

any Ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $Q = A-B$.  Since $QCA=B = A-Q$, $Q(CA+I)=A$, and therefore $Q$ is invertible.
Now $C = Q^{-1} B A^{-1} = Q^{-1}(A-Q)A^{-1} = Q^{-1} - A^{-1}$, so 
$AC(A-B) = A(Q^{-1} - A^{-1}) Q = A - Q = B$.

Comment: I could n't follow how Q−1(A−Q)A−1=Q−1−A−1 (last step in line 2 came to be).
Cheers

Comment: Just expand it out: $Q^{-1} (A - Q) A^{-1} = Q^{-1} A A^{-1} - Q^{-1} Q A^{-1}$ and then cancel: $Q^{-1} A A^{-1} = Q^{-1}$, $Q^{-1} Q A^{-1} = A^{-1}$.

Comment: It may be simple, but why does $Q(CA+I)=A$ make $Q$ invertible?

Comment: $A$ was assumed invertible.  $Q(CA+I)A^{-1} = I$.  Any $n \times n$ matrix with a one-sided inverse has rank $n$ and therefore is inverible.